DependencyInjectionException in JMeter Java Request
I am using JMeter Java Request to call java-client module of my micronaut microservice for load testing. Given below is the piece of code that I have written in my micronaut microservice. This code works fine when I run in IntelliJ IDE. However, when I build this code and create a fat jar and use that fat jar inside JMeter Java Request and run it, I get following error. So, what could be the solution to that issue?
Code:
import org.example.MyMicroserviceClient;
import io.micronaut.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.AbstractJavaSamplerClient;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSamplerContext;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;


public class App extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new App().runTest(null);
    }

    @Override
    public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext javaSamplerContext) {
        SampleResult result = new SampleResult();
        result.sampleStart();
        try {

            ApplicationContext applicationContext = ApplicationContext.run();

            MyMicroserviceClient client = applicationContext.getBean(MyMicroserviceClient.class);

            client.doSomething();

            result.sampleEnd();
            result.setSuccessful(true);
            result.setResponseData("response".getBytes());
            result.setResponseMessage("Request Successful");
            result.setResponseCodeOK(); // 200 code
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result.sampleEnd();
            result.setSuccessful(false);
            result.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e.toString());
            result.setResponseData(e.getMessage().getBytes());
        }
        return result;
    }
}

Error:
Thread Name:Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start:2024-04-11 03:24:11 CDT
Load time:1764
Connect Time:0
Latency:0
Size in bytes:814
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes:0
Body size in bytes:814
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):
Response code:
Response message:Exception: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException: Failed to inject value for parameter [readTimeout] of class: io.micronaut.discovery.client.config.DistributedPropertySourceLocator

Message: Failed to inject value for parameter [readTimeout] of class: io.micronaut.discovery.client.config.DistributedPropertySourceLocator

Message: Error resolving property value [${micronaut.config-client.read-timeout:10s}]. Property doesn't exist
Path Taken: new DistributedPropertySourceLocator(ConfigurationClient configurationClient,Duration readTimeout) --> new DistributedPropertySourceLocator(ConfigurationClient configurationClient,[Duration readTimeout])
Path Taken: new DistributedPropertySourceLocator(ConfigurationClient configurationClient,Duration readTimeout) --> new DistributedPropertySourceLocator(ConfigurationClient configurationClient,[Duration readTimeout])


SampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null

I have tried various things such as explicitly setting read-timeout value in yml properties files, bin/jmeter.sh file, bin/jmeter.properties file, environment variable, ApplicationContext, etc. but it did not work.

I don't think you can initialize a Spring application inside JMeter from Java Request sampler. See Run Spring Boot jar from standard Java application
If you just need to kick it off somewhere in setUp Thread Group to implement some preconditions - take a look at OS Process Sampler where you can run the executable .jar.
